# Magnetic field due to a double tape line

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, inductance

I have been asked to calculate the inductance of a double tape line :

[image]

Now we know that   $$ N\phi = LI$$ 
 So let's calculate the magnetic field by assuming an amperian loop like this:

[image]

$$\int B.dl = \mu_oI$$

But it seems to me that the current in the upper strip only contributes to the magnetic field though i know that the value of $B$ i get is the net magnetic field. How do we explain that the current in the lower strip also contributes to the magnetic field?

Comment: Consider each tape individually.  The only difference is that the current is running in opposite directions in the two tapes, so each tape with its current produces a magnetic field; it's just that the magnetic field goes clockwise around one and counterclockwise around the other.